# Notepad++ Pythonscript Can I import a module from the same folder as my pythonscript program?

Tags: python, module, notepad++

I have a pythonscript TestOnly.py running successfully in Notepad++ (using a shortcut Shift-F9 to run it). TestOnly.py is in
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\PythonScript\scripts\myfolder

```
console.clear()
console.show()
from myDict import *
print months
```

This works fine when myDict.py is in
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\PythonScript\scripts

But I want myDict.py to be in the same folder as TestOnly.py i.e.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\PythonScript\scripts\myfolder

When I run TestOnly.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts\myFolder\TestOnly.py", line 3, in <module>
    from myDict import *
ImportError: No module named myDict
```

I have put an empty __init__.py file in both folders but they don't seem to have any effect. Can anyone explain a simple way of getting around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 0):

The **simple** answer is:

Place an empty __init.py__ in myfolder

```
console.clear()
console.show()
from myfolder.myDict import *
print months
```